# Why did the "swift compilation time debugging options" cause CompileSwift to fail?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I use these flags in my project:

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = "-driver-time-compilation -Xfrontend -debug-time-compilation -Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies -Xfrontend -debug-time-expression-type-checking";
```

When I upgraded the Xcode version from 12.4 to 12.5.1, I started receiving this error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: unknown argument: '-debug-time-compilation'
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Has there been any llvm update or something like that?

Comment: I'm facing similar issue. Did you get the solution?

Comment: @RomitKumar yes I did. Check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's answer:

> Xcode 12.5 uses a new release of the Swift, Swift 5.4. Prior releases
> of Xcode 12 contained Swift 5.3, as documented here:
> https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode
> The debug-time-compilation flag is removed from Swift 5.4 because it no
> longer did anything, being superseded by the driver-time-compilation
> flag. You can see the commit of this change:
> https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/2198d7174c5857a92e42c5e76e1c1bb9a78db772